# Unix - Find files with the same name under a directory using ls

Tags: unix, find, ls

I want to list all suhosin.ini files under /etc/php5/ directory. The thing is that the 3 of them are one level deeper in the directory tree. I want to combine these two to one command

```
# ls  /etc/php5/*/*/suhosin.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/suhosin.ini  /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/suhosin.ini  /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/suhosin.ini

# ls  /etc/php5/*/suhosin.ini
/etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini
```

I tried to use `ls /etc/php5/ -R` and pipe it to grep but i couldnt do what i want which is get a list like that

```
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/suhosin.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/suhosin.ini
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/suhosin.ini
/etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
$ find /etc/php5 -name suhosin.ini
```